# Geo node (simulation node) cannot add velocity to an instance

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, simulation-nodes

I try to repeat the demo provided by Blender officials which allows the user to manipulate a big ball to pull other small balls with the use of geo nodes.
But when I try to add Velocity in the simulation node, I notice that if I input an instance in the simulation zoon, it can't be accelerated. Instead When I input a point, it speed up as expected.

[Bug demonstration](https://youtu.be/aNw5v37v4bA)
[Original file](https://github.com/lwl20001017/fenglvv/blob/main/TEST.blend)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why you want to instance the sphere before the simulation. The setup seems to work with a point and a given radius for the collision detection. So that is how I would do it:

First of all connect the "Radius" input with the *Value* input on the "COLLIDER" nodegroup because the radius determines the size of the instanced sphere and it would make perfectly sense if this radius would be used in the collision detection as well without the need to manually adjusting it.

Then you leave everything as it is with the domains all set to *Point* instead of *Instance*. The *Instance on Points* node has to be put after the *Simulation Zone*, so the simulation works with the point and the sphere is instanced on that.

[image: collider simulation]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I understand that instantiating the sphere after the simulation node can make sense. But theoretically speaking, instantiating before simulation and moving the instances in the simulation zone should have worked, cause they actually use the same logic: capture the current position, move instances(or points), and transfer the distance for the next SIMULATION INPUT. However, when I input instances in the simulation zone, the instance doesn't move as the point does. I don't know why it happens. Is it a bug or a feature that I don't know?

Comment: @Fenglvv I could not really get behind that issue either and since I am not yet very familiar with simulation nodes I cannot really tell if it is a bug or a feature or how to set it up so that it works correct with the instance. However, since using the sphere instance in the collision detection would not take the mesh into account but only the position as a single point, the simulation would not really benefit from instancing beforehand and maybe it might even be easier/quicker to calculate the simulation with a single point than with the sphere (but I do not know)...?